# MUI Autocomplete Inefficient with Large Lists - Seeking Alternatives or Optimization Strategies

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using Material-UI's Autocomplete component in a React project and facing performance issues when dealing with large lists of options. I'm specifically trying to filter job titles from a large dataset based on user input, expecting the Autocomplete to only show options that include the exact word inputted. However, it seems to struggle with larger lists.

Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
import Autocomplete from '@mui/material/Autocomplete';

    const largeListOfJobs = [
      // ... large dataset containing thousands of job titles
    ];
    
    const JobTitleAutocomplete = () => {
    
      return (
        <Autocomplete
          options={largeListOfJobs}
          inputValue={inputValue}
        />
      );
    };
    
    export default JobTitleAutocomplete;
```

In this setup, when the list of job titles is large, the filtering becomes inefficient. The component's responsiveness drops significantly, making the user experience less than ideal.

**Questions**:

1. Why does MUI Autocomplete struggle with large lists (600+), and is there a way to optimize its performance in such scenarios?
2. Are there any alternative approaches or components I should consider for efficiently handling large lists in an autocomplete functionality?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The MUI docs mention using the library react-window where they demo a list with 10k options.  Perhaps this could help?

https://mui.com/material-ui/react-autocomplete/#virtualization